# Need to Compress(reduce size) of Animated WEBP file - FFmpeg, libwebp

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, image-compression, animated-webp

I want to reduce WEBP file size. I'm using https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit library to convert my video .mp4 to .webp 
Input File MP4 Size - 800kb 
Output File WEBP size - 5.22 MB

Commands which i used

> **ffmpeg.exe -i outputbitrate.mp4 -vcodec libwebp -filter:v fps=fps=20 -lossless 1 -loop 0 -preset default -an -vsync 0 -vf scale=512:512:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,format=rgba,pad=512:512:-1:-1:color=#00000000 finalout.webp**

I tried with compress_level,quality also. which is not reducing the output size.
in mycase, the output should be less then 512kb. how to achieve this.
Any articles or sample code will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `-lossless 1` intentionally? Is the input mp4 file also lossless?

Comment: @kesh probably No, i'm directly trimming the video 10 seconds with following command  `-i input.mp4 -ss 00:00 -to 10:00 -r $FRAME_RATE -preset ultrafast output.mp4` and doing bitrate compress `fmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 800k output.mp4 `

Comment: Check out [this ffmpeg wiki article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9). I think it'll help your need. Definitely remove the lossless flag.

Comment: hey @kesh, tried that , same output same file size. i think ffmpeg already doing that itself.

Comment: Delete “-preset default”. It overrides your prams